# Read Ctrl, Alt and Shift keys from python CLI

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Writting a CLI program, I would like to read `Ctrl+<anything>` commands.

How can I listen and handle i.e.: `Ctrl+R` combination keys from my CLI python application?

For the moment, it is necessary only for Linux environments. An pythonic approach would be the best option, but I don't know how.

From signals, it is possible to handle well-known inputs, but not custom keystrokes.

Comment: You'll need to call directly into OS functions to get the state of those keys. Which OS are you running? Although the combination of Control and a letter will generate a character that you can detect.

Comment: Good. But, there is some pythonic way to do this, without write a OS-bound implementation? I believe that red from stdin is a clean approach ... But, I don't know how.

Comment: Is your goal to use *any* key with Control, or only the letters of the alphabet?

Comment: Yes. My purpose is build CLI tools supporting any command, like Ctrl+R to force reload, by example.

Answer (score 3):

[Pynput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput) is a package that's setup to handle mouse and keyboard input for a variety of operating systems. [This Github issue](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20) demonstrates how to detect held keys. If you don't want to follow the link:

```
from pynput import keyboard

# The key combination to check
COMBINATION = {keyboard.Key.cmd, keyboard.Key.ctrl}

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()


def on_press(key):
    if key in COMBINATION:
        current.add(key)
        if all(k in current for k in COMBINATION):
            print('All modifiers active!')
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        listener.stop()


def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: The [docs](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#linux) say "On Linux, pynput uses X, so an X server must be running". This limits the usage only to your local Linux desktop and will not work over SSH on a Linux machine without X.